# R: Collapse rows of a dataframe in particular format

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe

```
df1
             Col1              Col2       Col3  Col4    Col5
26287849 "N Engl J Med"    "2015 Aug 20" "373"  "8"    "726-36"   
25979833 "Eur J Cancer"    "2015 Jul"    "51"   "11"   "1405-14"  
25667274 "J Clin Oncol"    "2015 Mar 20" "33"   "9"    "1000-7"   
25430497 "J Clin Pathol"   "2015 Feb"    "68"   "2"    "111-8"
```

I am trying to collapse each row in the dataframe so that the output format shown below. With 2 columns, PMID and reference. A specific reference format.  Any input is helpful. Thank you.

```
 PMID       Reference
 26287849 N Engl J Med. 2015 Aug 20;373(8):726-36
 25979833 Eur J Cancer. 2015 Jul;    51(11): 1405-14  
 25667274 J Clin Oncol. 2015 Mar 20; 33(9): 1000-7   
 25430497 J Clin Pathol.2015 Feb;    68(2): 111-8
```

Comment: Perhaps `data.frame(PMID= row.names(df1), Reference = sprintf('%s. %s;%s(%s):%s', df1$Col1, df1$Col2, df1$Col3, df1$Col4, df1$Col5))`

Comment: In your `Reference` column there are uneven spaces for each element.  Is that a typo?

Comment: Yeah, that is typo. Thank you for the solution. It works . However, When I am trying to produce the output using Rshiny I have issue. Will work on it and get back. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do this using `base R` (assuming that the uneven spaces in the 'Reference' column are typo).  We create a new 'data.frame' with two columns, i.e. one based on the row names of 'df1'  and the second by pasting the columns using `sprintf`.

```
df2 <- data.frame(PMID= row.names(df1),
                  Reference = sprintf('%s. %s;%s(%s):%s',
                    df1$Col1, df1$Col2, df1$Col3, df1$Col4, df1$Col5),
                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```